# How can I return a new object based on a filter?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this js:

```
var json = {"products":[{"id":"6066157707315577","reference_prefix":"BB","name":"BeanieBaby","product_line":false,"has_ideas":true},{"id":"6066197229601550","reference_prefix":"BBAGS","name":"BlackBags","product_line":false,"has_ideas":false}],"pagination":{"total_records":4,"total_pages":1,"current_page":1}}

var stuff = json.products.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.has_ideas === true
});

console.log(stuff);
```

I need help returning a js obj in the same format it started in (var json = {"products":[...) but containing only the filtered objects if they exist.  If not, i just want an empty array.  How do I do this?

Comment: `var stuffObj = {products: stuff}`

Comment: Please be aware that what you are assigning to `json` is an **object**, and the specific syntax is called *object literal*, not JSON. And it's certainly *not* a string. JavaScript is a *programming language*, JSON is *data format*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create your object and fill in its 'products' property :

```
var jsonObj = {"products":[{"id":"6066157707315577","reference_prefix":"BB","name":"BeanieBaby","product_line":false,"has_ideas":true},{"id":"6066197229601550","reference_prefix":"BBAGS","name":"BlackBags","product_line":false,"has_ideas":false}],"pagination":{"total_records":4,"total_pages":1,"current_page":1}}

var stuff = {};
stuff.products = jsonObj.products.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.has_ideas === true
});

console.log(stuff);
```